# What true in one L-structure, but not the other?

Tags: logic

I have two L-structures, $A=(\mathbb Z,+)$ and $B=(\mathbb Q,+)$ where + is a binary function and is addition as usual. What is an example of something that is true in A but not in B to do with the binary function symbol +?

Comment: I'm looking for a example something to do with addition that is true in A, but not true in B. Or the other way around since I can just negate the statement then. I'll edit my post

Comment: ah yes, that is that you cannot obtain every number in the integers but adding the same number twice together but you can in the rationals. i.e.e you cannot obtain 3 in the integers by adding two numbers together, but you can do this in the rationals (1.5+1.5). Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence
$$\exists x\forall y\ (y+y\ne x)$$
is true in $A$ but false in $B.$